# incorrect my sql select statement results

Tags: php, mysql

I have small mysql table with:

`id` `name` `status` `class` `desk` `date` `username`

It has around 300 records.

When selecting data to get the latest record by `date` (formatted), along with `username`, I use this statement:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MAX(date), '%d-%m-%Y at %H:%i'), username as LatestRecord from myTable
```

It returns the correct record for dateTime but gives different `username` which is not in the same selected row. It seems like it doesn't select the `username` for the same resulted lastest date/time.

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the latest record then you should add an `ORDER BY` and a `LIMIT` clausule's to your query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y at %H:%i') as LatestDate, username as LatestRecord 
FROM myTable
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: thanks, this works although it is a little longer than expected :)